# Is there a way to get the value of span and save to database in classic asp

Tags: javascript, asp-classic

Is there a way to get the value of span and save to database in classic asp.

and also is there a way to put a onChange event on a span?

Answer (score 0):

The onchange attribute can only be used with: `<input>, <select>, and <textarea>.`

Comment: Oh I see. The problem is that the span value is being supplied from an ajax function. And I can't make it work if I use an input box.